# Node app not writing to a file, no error logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, fs

I am trying to use [Capture-Website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-website) which saves screenshots of webpages to a file.

It used to work perfectly until I restarted the server.

Now the code runs without errors, but it does NOT save a screenshot to disk

Here is my code:

```
import http from 'http';
import url from 'url';
import querystring from 'querystring';

var mainURL;

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 8080;


import captureWebsite from 'capture-website';


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;
    mainURL = query.url;
    console.log(mainURL);
    (async () => {
        try {
            await captureWebsite.file('https://'+mainURL, mainURL+".jpg", {
                overwrite:true,
                type: 'jpeg',
                quality: 0.5,
                width:1480,
                height:800,
                delay: 1
            });
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })();
    
});
```

There are no errors. I have also tried running `pm2 logs` - no errors there either.

Here is the file-writing code that belongs to the `capture-website` package:

```
captureWebsite.file = async (url, filePath, options = {}) => {
    const screenshot = await internalCaptureWebsite(url, options);

    
    await fs.writeFile(filePath, screenshot, {
        flag: options.overwrite ? 'w' : 'wx',
    });
    
};
```

Comment: please, provide your pm2 ecosystem configuration

Comment: @michalpavlik There's nothing noteworthy in there

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you can not use Slashes (/) in file names. This is because folders are seperated with slashes.

Comment: Tried - doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You will need to remove all characters that are not allowed. :, /, \, ?, etc.

Comment: Yep, still doesn't work. It also used to work before, but after restarting the server it stopped working

Comment: Could it be that your NodeJS process has no permissions to write a file there?